# Flash Builder 4.6 issue: Access to undefined property - clean its not the answer

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a lot of strange info in my project in Flash Builder, why ?

"Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant" and 
"Access to undefined property", "Call to a possibly undefined method "

When i go to those class and make space " " and save, parrent class is ok, 
cleaning doesnt help for long time.

What is the problem ?

code-example:

```
import utils.DbUtils;
....
....
public function afterDbInit():void{
                personsCollection = DbUtils.getAllObjects();
                calendarViewId.loadDefaultCalendar();
            }
```

[image: flash-builder-issue]

but its not problem with CODE, it Flash Builder iSSUE, when i found DbUtils Class File, and opne it, made one space more and save, issue gone.

Project is compiling but i cannot use ctrl+lpm to go to the selected class file, compiler doesnt seen it

personsCollection = **DbUtils**.getAllObjects();

but after few debbuggging runs, this exlamation icon, and orange dot appear again

---

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import database.DBConnection;
            import database.Database;
            import database.DatabaseEvent;
            import database.DatabaseResponder;
```

i have all imports there

Comment: Call to a possibly undefined method - another strange message

Comment: Is the code with a problem in a library, or calling code in a library?

Comment: Maybe more of the stack trace, or the full error message  . . . it will contain more info including class names and so on.

Comment: its problem with method and also with classess ...
i have some Utils class - and when i go to this class, make one space more and save, then i see this class i other components -

Comment: if i dont 'refresh' class file i have strange info:  Access of undefined property

Comment: Got the same problem with the JSON class from external library.

Answer (score 2):

I found something interesting about my "Access to Undefined Property" warnings that might help someone.

I was working on a module (ofcMtc.mxml and ofcMtc.as)  of which I later decided I didn't like the design.   So I renamed both the mxml and action script files to a different name in order to save off the work  (ofcMtcOLD.mxml and ofcMtcOLD.as).

Then I recreated that same module using the original file names for both the mxml and action script.

Now keep in mind the OLD version still had a line of code in the mxml associating the original action script file name (mx:script source="ofcMtc.as") - and it was picking this up in the compiling - causing the warnings to appear in my new version.

By removing the mx:script code from the OLD mxml file - the warnings went away in the new version.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a class that contains a public variable. It showed up as "undefined property" when trying to access the property even though the code works well. The Quick Fix / Assist (Ctrl + 1) asked to create the property, so i tabbed and pressed enter to have the code completion help me with that. The editor removed the warning, but did no changes to my class.

I'd say this is a weird bug, and just wanted to let anyone else that gets this issue that the Quick Fix / Assist can actually help out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If DataBaseEvent is an external class, not the one bundled with Flex, you could try referencing it by it's full name.

For example, i got the same error with custom implementation of JSON (package vk.api.serialization.json)

I had to change all lines like

```
JSON.encode(data)
```

to

```
vk.api.serialization.json.JSON.encode(data)
```

It helped.

Answer (score 0):

The approach to specify the full qualified class name worked also for me.

Thus, i change the class definition from

`public class NumberInputBase extends TextInput`

to

`public class NumberInputBase extends mx.controls.TextInput`

Answer (score -1):

You haven't imported the DatabaseEvent type. On a Windows PC, Ctrl+Shift+O should organise your imports.

Comment: all imports are ok

<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
   import database.DBConnection;
   import database.Database;
   import database.DatabaseEvent;
   import database.DatabaseResponder;

Comment: Make sure `database.DatabaseEvent` is defined

Comment: Everything is defined - Flash Builder just go crazy. 
Sometimes i just need to change name in class 
for Example - DbUtils -> to DbUtilX - and change it in all project - after than problems gone, Why The F*** ?

Comment: Maybe because there is already a DatabaseEvent (though that *shouldn't* make a difference). To change all the references to a class, you just need to rename it in the project explorer.

Comment: hmm, it will be quite difficult beceause im using a lot of additional libraries